# What is wrong with GCHeapFreeLimit?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

i find this:

-XX:GCHeapFreeLimit=2  - defines minimum percentage of free space after a full GC before an OutOfMemoryError is thrown

but when i try to use this option in my application i faced with the problem

My JVM's options are:

```
-server -d64 -Xss256k
-verbose:gc
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-Xms332m
-Xmx332m
-XX:NewSize=128m
-XX:MaxNewSize=128m

-XX:PermSize=64m
-XX:MaxPermSize=64m
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
-XX:+UseParNewGC

-XX:ParallelGCThreads=2
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=2
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1
-XX:SurvivorRatio=8
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:GCHeapFreeLimit=40
-XX:GCTimeLimit=70
```

So (-XX:GCHeapFreeLimit=40) i suppose that if after full GC free heep size will be less then 40% i will see OOME. But it doesn't heppends. I have a lot of similar log messages:

```
[Full GC [CMS2013-08-15T14:20:47.068+0100: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.200/0.203 secs] [Times: user=0.38 sys=0.02, real=0.20 secs]
 (concurrent mode failure): 208895K->208895K(208896K), 0.8387700 secs] 326911K->304069K(326912K), [CMS Perm : 35941K->35939K(65536K)], 0.8388880 secs] [Times
: user=0.83 sys=0.00, real=0.84 secs]
```

where i can see that (326911-304069)/326911 more than 60%. But my application doesn't fail.

Comment: The more options you use, the more than interact and you are likely to get a combination which does not work as intended.  I would only add options if you really, really need to.  I suggest you try removing almost all the options and try again.

Comment: Why do you have `ParallelGCThreads` twice?

Answer (score 3):

the OOME error is thrown when all the following 3 conditions are true (This text is from Java performance tuning book by Scott Oaks)

1. The amount of time spent in full GCs exceeds the value specified by the
   `-XX:GCTimeLimit=N` flag. The default value is 98 (i.e., if 98% of the time is spent in GC).
2. The amount of memory reclaimed by a full GC is less than the value specified by the `-XX:GCHeapFreeLimit=N` flag. The default value for this is 2, meaning that if
   less than 2% of the heap is freed during the full GC, this condition is met.
3. The above two conditions have held true for five consecutive full GC cycles (that value is not tunable).

In your case, JVM may be freeing up less than 60% of memory but JVM may not be freeing less than 60% for 5 consecutive cycles or JVM is not spending more than 70% time in GC for 5 consecutive cycles or combination of the above.

Answer (score 1):

This is not what this option is about. From [here](https://polly97.wordpress.com/2007/06/13/a-collection-of-jvm-options/):

> Used with -XX:+UseParallelGC to help prevent out-of-memory exceptions
>   from occuring during garbage collection. This parameter specifies the
>   lower limit on the amount of space freed during a garbage collection
>   in per cent of the maximum heap (default is 5).

So the option is used to potentially **prevent** OOME by making GC more aggressive.

There's really little reason why you would have control over when the OOME happens, since its purpose is to be thrown when there's no more space on the heap to allocate for objects. There's not much point in artificially making it occur earlier. While, [as you've already found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230489/how-can-i-help-cms-gc-die-fast), there are options for this, I'd argue it goes against the [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) of the class. Do you really want to inflict a potentiall conundrum on other developers maintaining your code later on?